# vb .net webclient downloaddata with new lines

Tags: vb.net, webclient

I'm using webclient downloaddata to download some "plain text" outputed by an website.

Everything is working good, and I'm saving all text in a new txt.
My problem is with text formatting.

For example, the website outputs like this (each info in a new line):

```
Name - John Doe
Age - 33
City - New York
```

But when I save that data in a file, it saves like:

```
Name - John DoeAge - 33City - New York
```

Anyone knows how can I make it write the file as it shows in the web page?

My code right now:

```
    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    For value As Integer = 1 To TextBox3.Text
        Dim WebClient As WebClient = New WebClient()
        WebClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode
        Dim sourceString As Byte() = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData(TextBox1.Text & value & TextBox2.Text)
        Dim htmlCode = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sourceString)
        Dim filepath = "C:\Project\" & value & ".txt"
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(filepath, htmlCode)
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(value)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try checking the string you receive in a text editor that will show hidden characters, like Word or Notepad++. You may be getting a line feed character that should instead be a Carriage-Return Line Feed. If that is the case you can convert it like this.

```
htmlCode = htmlCode.Replace(vbLF, vbCrLf)
```

Answer (score 0):

The downloaded file actually has multiple lines, but you cannot see them in Windows's built-in Notepad application (nor in a regular `TextBox`).

The reason to this is because the two only detect line endings of the **CrLf** format (*Carriage return + Line feed*), though since many webservers are built on a Unix or Unix-like system (such as Linux) they use only **Lf** (*Line feed*) as line endings. Some servers even converts text files into the **Lf** format when you upload them, which means that a file could originally have Windows's line endings but when uploaded the server converts them to the Unix format.

What you can do in this case is convert it yourself by replacing all line endings with **CrLf**. A [**`Regex`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) replacing every line ending (even correct ones, to ensure that all are the same) would be the best for this:

```
Dim htmlCode = Regex.Replace(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sourceString), "\r\n|\r|\n", Environment.NewLine)
```